# I see Britain, I see France, I see Wonder Woman's... satin tights?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edit

So I'm curious on what the community thinks about the latest hot question [being edited](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/106603)

From

> Have there ever been 25 or more stars on Wonder Woman's panties?

To

> Have there ever been 25 or more stars on Wonder Woman's satin tights?

The edit really doesn't make sense. Wonder Woman has a skimpy outfit that has multiple parts that really don't have their own words, apart from their underwear counterparts (which is essentially what she wears). And the title is mirroring the language used in the reason for the question in the first place. But, most importantly, *Wonder Woman doesn't wear tights*. And in the [limited places the character has not worn the traditional suit](https://letterpile.com/books/Wonder-Woman-Costume-History)... there's no stars.

So... are `panties` too racy for SF? Do we revert it back? Or do we try another word?

---

Current title:

[Have there ever been 25 or more stars on Wonder Woman's "panties"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/161177/19561)

Comment: Those aren't panties. That's the lower half of a bodysuit

Comment: We could call it a suit for that matter. But the current edit invalidates what appears to be the intent of the author. The question here is is the word itself inappropriate?

Comment: Are you asking whether the word is inappropriate or whether the question has been edited inappropriately? As the comments have pointed out, the term "satin tights" is actually part of the established canon to describe her outfit...

Comment: Is the word `panties` inappropriate? If it's not, the question has a legitimate reason to use that specific term. And I'm not sure the lyrics from a TV show theme count as canon (if you read the full lyrics, it's pretty clear they picked that term so they could rhyme with it).

Comment: I think you either use the canonical term, or something a little more appropriate, because her bottoms just aren't panties, panties are a form of undergarment, and the OP was definitely not asking about WW's undergarments. As Valorum pointed out it's the bottom half of a body suit, or a tankini.

Comment: @Machavity - I've voted to close as unclear. You appear to be conflating two distinct questions.

Comment: @Valorum The question uses panties because the rap video uses panties.  The edit implies the word is inappropriate. Nothing unclear about that. If you want to have a terminology discussion we can have one. But this isn't my terminology we're debating either (nor my preferences)

Comment: @Machavity - The "intent" is for the OP to learn about the stars on the lower half of her outfit, not to use the word panties. The specific language used is largely irrelevant.

Comment: @Valorum:   I disagree. The question is clearly motivated by the lyrics in the ERB rap -- otherwise why 25 stars as the cutoff.   It should use the same term as the source of motivation.

Comment: To weigh in on the term and not the debate of intent, no, the term panties shouldn't be too racy, although given our usual maturity level, any given question about them may be and should be evaluated on their own.

Comment: I posted that question. I don't care either way. I find the discussion it has generated hilarious.

Comment: She's essentially wearing an altered version of what ballerinas wear when they're practicing - the leotard-thingie without the tutu around it. So what is that kind of outfit called? Also, I have no idea what "ERB rap" is being referred to - I thought "I see Paris, I see France, I see Wonder Woman's underpants" (or however it goes) was a children's rhyme from way back.

Comment: The real-world term is "hot pants" or "short shorts".

Comment: Uh, guys? The bottom part of a bikini is also called panties. Like every single other word in every single language in the known universe, *panties* has more than one meaning.

Comment: @Omegacron A leotard without a tutu is called a leotard.

Comment: @Martha I've only ever heard "bikini bottom" for it.

Comment: @Stormblessed Is that a whitespace edit?

Comment: @Simpleton it updated the “current title” link by making it render the current title again

Comment: @Storm oh, i thought that this issue with the wonder woman edits was being kicked up again

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It should use the original title containing the word "panties".

The question is clearly motivated by the lyrics in the ERB rap -- otherwise why use 25 stars as the cutoff. It should use the same term as the source of motivation.

As an alternate middleground, I might suggest the word could be placed in quotes.

Justifications of why the quotes are appropriate:

1. It is a quote from the rap.
2. There is a very good argument they are not actually panties.
3. It acknowledges that the usage is potentially contentious.

---

## RESOLVED

In accordance with the 12-0 vote as of this moment, I'm going to take the honour of editing the original question.

Comment: I like the suggestion of quotation marks. I think it would allow the title to use the relevant wording while also showing that it's being used in a technical way rather than being vulgar or immature.

Comment: Six upvotes, no downvotes in an hour.

Comment: @BiscuitBaker I actually think the quotes would make it seem more taboo

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd:   Quotes are appropriate for **three** reasons:  (1) it is a quote from the rap, (2) there is a very good argument they are not actually panties, (3) it acknowledges that the usage is potentially contentious.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I was speaking in general terms, since the question is whether 'panties' is a racy term for this site, rather than canonical. Normally when people see a word in quotes, it's implied that something about it is questionable.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - That's a separate question. You have to ask them one at a time.

Comment: @Valorum Huh? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Valorum I'm not asking any questions. And you're first example is the one being asked by the OP, which is what I was addressing in my earlier comment.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Sorry, I thought I was addressing the OP

Comment: An alternative to quotes would be to add [sic] to the end.

Comment: In light of the 12-0 vote as of this moment, I'm going to take the honour of editing the original question.