# Favorite Questions and Answers from second quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from April 1st 2017 through June 30 2017 (**They don't have to be *your* questions and answers, but it also doesn't matter if you want to self promote your own stuff.**).

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/04/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/04/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/04/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter.**

Also if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

### Votes

People sometimes down-vote the answers, even going as far as to target specific people and vote them into the negative. Just so you know, that is a pointless practice. All answers are included regardless of vote count (unless I decide not to include one for some reason). Also the vote score does not determine the order in which things will appear in the post, I tend to arbitrarily do that when I write it up.

Comment: I've actually been waiting for this. What took you so long?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd it takes me three months to ask this question.

Comment: How about favorite [comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157637/are-draco-and-harry-related/157657#comment413336_157637)?

Comment: @ibid I've never done comments before but I'm willing to try it, within reason.

Comment: @JackBNimble No excuses

Comment: If the answer was edited recently, but not posted recently, would it be eligible for nomination?

Comment: Can we do [meta questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11010/i-see-britain-i-see-france-i-see-wonder-womans-satin-tights)?

Comment: @Kevin [Meta Posts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9848/54887) and [events](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10768/54887) have been featured in the past. Recommend away!

Answer (score 10):

I'm biased, because it's my question, but I really like DCOPTimDowd's [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/161713/23243) to my question of [What went down at the July 1974 Comic Art Con?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161712/what-went-down-at-the-july-1974-comic-art-con). He put quite a bit of effort into explaining the circumstances and the people involved. It's a bit of an odd duck as a question on the site, being about the fandom, but people seem to have received it well.

Comment: I was also really surprised how much attention it got. I'm glad though, because it was super fun to answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

NB: I've selected these items on the basis of being *interesting*, so they are not necessarily correct or "useful."

### Favorite question

In [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/156511/36526), we learned that Hobbes's existence is deliberately ambiguous.  Not content with that, Machavity then asked **[Does Hobbes ever do anything that Calvin himself could not do?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/156596/36526)**, which is an interesting way to approach the problem and generated a significant amount of discussion in several different directions.

### Favorite answer

Edlothiad's **[answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/161738/36526)** to the question about whether Galadriel's temptation of Boromir was "instrumental to his fall" was very thorough and made me think about both characters in a different way.  I'm not sure how true it is, but it's quite thought provoking, moreso than the highest-voted answer.

(Quite a lot of people in the comments to that answer seem to think it's claiming that Galadriel was somehow "evil," but I don't see that claim in the answer itself, nor in any of the older versions of it, so I am disregarding all of that criticism as unsound.  Nevertheless, the answer may be reaching in some other aspects relating to Boromir's state of mind, so I'm not about to claim it's accurate in that respect.)

### Favorite Meta

**[I see Britain, I see France, I see Wonder Woman's... satin tights?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11010/36526)** has the funniest title I've seen on Meta in a while.  It's also a great example of the collaborative process working as intended.

### Shameless self-promotion

[**Image questions**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/156312/36526) are always fun to answer.  They help break up the monotonous giant walls of text I always end up writing.

Comment: Thanks for agreeing that I didn't say Galadriel was Evil, I've been driving myself up the wall to try and figure out that one

Answer (score 4):

### **Favorite Question**

> Selecting from one of my own this time: [Did Anakin want kids?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/159794/75000). I thought it was a pretty good idea for a question and it was definitely one of the ones I did the most research on before posting. If only there was more information on it.

### **Favorite Answer**

> Thunderforge's [response](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/158062/75000) to my question of whether or not Pokemon can die while inside their Pokeballs. While it doesn't directly answer the question (to no fault of his own), it does give lots of insight on what is likely and I don't think we'll get any better an answer given the current available information.

### **Honorable Mention**

> The question [Have there ever been 25 or more stars on Wonder Woman's "panties"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/161177/75000) generated quite a bit of a [flubbub](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11010/75000) over whether or not the word "panties" is appropriate for this stack. As always, nerd controversies (especially over a superhero's underwear) are good fun and enjoyable to read.

Answer (score 4):

This is my first quarter actually contributing to scifi.se and here are two answers I am particularly proud of:

[How long did it take the Millennium Falcon to do the Kessel run](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/158494/62201) - Though I had to bend over backwards to do so, I feel I was able to get all the various information to resolve nicely into a legitimate answer. Especially given the (in)famous nature of the subject.

[Which lightsaber form did Obi-Wan use against Maul on Tatooine?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/161235/62201) - Post-Phantom Menace lightsaber duels are fascinating and exciting, so being able to analyze and breakdown the fight in question was nothing short of fun. I mean, who doesn't love to spend an afternoon exploring wookiepedia and everything it has on lightsabers?

And one that isn't mine:

In answering "[Does anyone know what this fantasy script is from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/160823/62201)", [santyclause](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/72448/santyclause) not only answered first, but was able to provide a legend for the script/alphabet that was pretty damn close to the "real" answer. All without knowing where the language came from (Brian Jacques' Redwall).

Answer (score 2):

### Shameless self promotion

I haven't nominated myself before, but I have some answers that I put some work into:

- [How big is the town of Gravity Falls?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117555/how-big-is-the-town-of-gravity-falls/157516#157516) because I compared lots of stuff, including images, real-life maps, and Oregon prison statistics.
- [Why was the Black Pearl so special?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156403/why-was-the-black-pearl-so-special/156408#156408) because I had to buy and read a whole *Pirates of the Caribbean* novel, which was not very good, to answer the question.

OK, I have a bunch more I put work into and am proud of, but it'd be a bit too shameless to have an "honored mentions" category for myself.